# How to "refresh" dependency packages with main project in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, pubspec

I am new to flutter development. I am trying to separate my code into multiple local packages as dependencies. Here's my current project structure:

/packages/`commons`: a package containing common widgets & utility functions

/packages/`fruits`: a package containing screens about fruits (depends upon: `commons`)

/`main`: depends upon `commons` & `fruits`

Whenever I make a dependency-change¹ in `commons` package that affects `fruits` package, I have to execute `flutter pub get` in three folders(for `commons`, `fruits` and main-project) to be able to run code.

Is there any way to reduce this process to a single "refresh" click?

---

1. Example in `commons`:

```
flutter pub add fluro
flutter pub get
```

Comment: You might be interested in [mono_repo](https://pub.dev/packages/mono_repo) or alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

Since I was getting impatient, I thought of writing a small shell-script for this. I don't know if there is an easier way, but this worked for me.

My project has following folder structure:

```sh
project
   pubspec.yaml
   packages/
       package1/
           pubspec.yaml
       package2/
           pubspec.yaml
       package3/
           pubspec.yaml
```

I created a `refresh.bash` file in project folder. Here's how it looks like:

```
# open project directory or exit if failed
cd PROJECT_PATH || exit
# check if project contains pubspec.yaml file
if [ -f "pubspec.yaml" ]; then
    # check if packages folder exists
    if [ -d "packages" ]; then
        # open packages folder
        cd "packages" || exit
        # run for all subdirectories of packages folder
        for d in */; do
            # open subdirectory
            cd "$d" || exit
            # check if subdirectory contains pubspec.yaml file
            if [ -f "pubspec.yaml" ]; then
                # run pub get for subdirectory (package)
                flutter pub get
            fi
            # exit subdirectory
            cd ..
        done
        # exit packages directory
        cd ..
    fi

    # run pub get for project directory
    flutter pub get
else
    echo "pubspec.yaml not found"
fi
```

Replace `PROJECT_PATH` with path to your project.

To be able to run this script, I had to make it executable. This can be done with following command:

```
chmod +x refresh.bash
```

After this, I ran the script (in bash terminal) with:

```
./refresh.bash
```

---

Note: I don't know how shell-scripts work as well, I took some hints from a [Shell Script Cheatsheet](https://devhints.io/bash). So, if there are any issues, or if it can be smaller, please suggest me. This is my first day with shell-scripting.